# Sequelize where clause is not on the top level

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

The `WHERE` clause is inside the nested `SELECT`, even though it is described in the root object of Sequelize `findAll()`.

**My controller:**

```
  const whereClause = req.query.search ? {
    $or: [
      '$Request.id$',
      '$Request.action$', // TODO: change to action name
      // '$Devices.id$',
      // '$Devices.Article.manufacturer$',
      // '$Devices.Article.model$',
      '$OldHolder.displayname$',
      '$NewHolder.displayname$',
    ].map(key => ({
      [key]: {
        $like: `%${req.query.search}%`,
      }
    }))
  } : {
    // default where
  }

  const items = await Request.findAll({
    where: whereClause,
    order: orderClause,
    limit: req.query.rowsPerPage != -1 ? +req.query.rowsPerPage || total : total,
    offset: req.query.page * req.query.rowsPerPage - req.query.rowsPerPage || 0,
    attributes: [ 'id', 'created_at', 'action', 'old_holder', 'new_holder' ],
    include: [
      {
        model: Device,
        as: 'Devices',
        attributes: ['id'],
        through: {attributes: []},
        include: [
          {
            model: Article,
            attributes: ['manufacturer', 'model', 'image_thumb']
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        model: User,
        as: 'OldHolder',
        attributes: ['id', 'displayname']
      },
      {
        model: User,
        as: 'NewHolder',
        attributes: ['id', 'displayname']
      }
    ]
  })
```

With current syntax I only managed to search by Request.id and Request.action.

**Resulting SQL:**

```
SELECT `Request`.*, `Devices`.`id` AS `Devices.id`, `Devices->device_request`.`device_id` AS `Devices.device_request.device_id`, `Devices->device_request`.`request_id` AS `Devices.device_request.request_id`, `Devices->Article`.`id` AS `Devices.Article.id`, `Devices->Article`.`manufacturer` AS `Devices.Article.manufacturer`, `Devices->Article`.`model` AS `Devices.Article.model`, `Devices->Article`.`image_thumb` AS `Devices.Article.image_thumb`, `OldHolder`.`id` AS `OldHolder.id`, `OldHolder`.`displayname` AS `OldHolder.displayname`, `NewHolder`.`id` AS `NewHolder.id`, `NewHolder`.`displayname` AS `NewHolder.displayname`
FROM (
SELECT `Request`.`id`, `Request`.`created_at`, `Request`.`action`, `Request`.`old_holder`, `Request`.`new_holder`
FROM `request` AS `Request`
WHERE (`Request`.`id` LIKE '%stock%' OR `Request`.`action` LIKE '%stock%' OR `NewHolder`.`displayname` LIKE '%stock%')
ORDER BY `Request`.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 0, 10) AS `Request`
LEFT OUTER
JOIN (`device_request` AS `Devices->device_request`
INNER JOIN `device` AS `Devices` ON `Devices`.`id` = `Devices->device_request`.`device_id`) ON `Request`.`id` = `Devices->device_request`.`request_id`
LEFT OUTER
JOIN `device_info` AS `Devices->Article` ON `Devices`.`device_info_id` = `Devices->Article`.`id`
LEFT OUTER
JOIN `user` AS `OldHolder` ON `Request`.`old_holder` = `OldHolder`.`id`
LEFT OUTER
JOIN `user` AS `NewHolder` ON `Request`.`new_holder` = `NewHolder`.`id`;
```

But I need this `WHERE` to be e.g. at the end of the query, then it works just fine.

Is it possible to move it outside the nested `SELECT` clause?

The Request is related to Device with belongs To Many.

Comment: How about nesting `whereClause` inside of the last join in `include`?

Comment: It just adds it inside AND after INNER JOINs: INNER JOIN `device_info` AS `Devices->Article` ON `Devices`.`device_info_id` = `Devices->Article`.`id` AND (`OldHolder.displayname` LIKE '%st%' OR `NewHolder`.`displayname` LIKE '%st%')) ON `Request`.`id` = `Devices->device_request`.`request_id`

Comment: Ok, revert that change. I noticed you're using the nested column syntax_i.e._ `$nested.column$` in your where clause. Try removing the `$` prefix and suffix in the column names

Comment: Yes, that was how I managed to search by Request fields, but then it adds 'Request'. prefix to the other column names like this: `Request`.`OldHolder.displayname`, and when I tried to use sequelize.literal(), there was an [Object object] instead of raw string